# How to work with controls inside the Panels that are already inside a FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a view, something like a timeline in video-making tools.
I am using `FlowLayoutPanel` that will contain all my additional "tracks" in vertical type.
Every "track" is a `FlowLayoutPanel` that includes Buttons. The `FlowLayoutPanel` is one for the whole `Form`.
FlowLayoutPanels include Buttons that I am generating dynamically from code.

Now my code can generate FlowLayoutPanels inside the `FlowLayoutPanel` one by one.
But how can I work (resize, delete, change content) with generated FlowLayout Panels and controls that I am adding inside main `FlowLayoutPanel`?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to help us help you, please post some code and make your question more specific as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample based on your view. hope this will help you to clear it out. you can add your required stuffs one by one.

```
    private Dictionary<string, FlowLayoutPanel> tracks = new Dictionary<string, FlowLayoutPanel>();
    public TestFlowLayout()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        // for test
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            AddTrack("Track" + i.ToString());

            for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
            {
                AddButton("Track" + i.ToString(), "Button" + j.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddTrack(string name)
    {
        FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        panel.AutoSize = true;
        panel.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        this.Controls.Add(panel);
        tracks.Add(name, panel);
    }

    public void AddButton(string name, string caption)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Text = caption;
        tracks[name].Controls.Add(button);
    }
```

In case, you need track like group by group then you can change your code little bit

```
    public void AddTrack(string name)
    {
        GroupBox group = new GroupBox();
        group.Text = name;
        group.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        group.AutoSize = false;
        this.Controls.Add(group);
        group.BringToFront();
        FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        panel.SizeChanged += Panel_SizeChanged;
        panel.AutoSize = true;
        panel.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        group.Controls.Add(panel);
        tracks.Add(name, panel);
    }

    private void Panel_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FlowLayoutPanel panel = (FlowLayoutPanel)sender;
        panel.Parent.Height = panel.Size.Height+20;
    }
```